# Reading from table being created in transaction

Tags: sql-server, transaction, isolation-level

I would like to view data in a table that is undergoing a transaction. I will use this super simple temporary table as an example:

```
SELECT 5 AS NUMBER INTO ##temptable
```

I will create a transaction to insert a new row with the number 10:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
    INSERT INTO ##temptable 
    SELECT 10 AS Number
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20';
COMMIT TRAN;
```

Now, if I open a new query, and do a regular select statement, I will not get any results, the wheel will be spinning until the transaction has been committed. I can instead set the isolation level to read committed:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

I would expect this to return the committed number 5 but not the uncomitted number 10, but again I just get a spinning wheel. I guess that is not how it works.

If I set the isolation level to read uncommited:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

This successfully returns both numbers from the table.

I still have a problem though, because I want to create the table inside of the transaction like so:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRAN;
    SELECT 5 AS NUMBER INTO ##temptable

    INSERT INTO ##temptable 
    SELECT 10 AS Number
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20';
COMMIT TRAN;
```

In this case I once again get a spinning wheel if I try to read from the table, even with isolation level set to read uncommitted.

Is there any way to read from a table that is being created within an ongoing transaction?

Comment: Why do you need a global temp table anyway? A local temp table (with a single `#`) will be completely separated from any other sessions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not. Creating a table requires a schema modification lock, which isn't with compatible anything, not even a schema stability lock which is used when doing read uncommitted.

You most likely have to take a step back and re-think your approach. I.e.,create the table before the transaction.

Comment: Thank you, but what a shame. The temporary table is only ment as a staging table to prepare some data, and should be dropped after being used. I don't want to the run the risk of it not getting disposed properly. I will go back to the drawing board.

Comment: The temp table is dropped at end of connection/session, if that helps. Or, if possible, throw this in a stored procedure. A temp table created in a proc will disappear at end-of-proc.

Comment: Thank you, what I ment was, I don't want to create a persistent table, because it might not get disposed properly. It will be too complex to explain the remaining problem in the comments, I will open a new question instead.